# The "new" keyword (for methods) and OOP

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, overriding

OK. I *think* I understand the difference between `new` and `override`. But if my understanding is correct, isn't `new` keyword against the principles of OOP? With it, I can create a method in the child class that has a different signature than the base class, right? Like this:

```
class MyBase
{
    public int[] SampleMethod() { ... }
}

class MyChild : MyBase
{
    public new string[] SampleMethod() { ... }
}
```

A client would expect a class inheriting from `MyBase` to have a method named `SampleMethod` that returns an `int` array, but the child class doesn't. This is unlike `override` which I *think* requires the child method to have the same signature as parent. What am I missing?

Comment: You may want to specify what you consider "principles of OOP" for this particular question... Otherwise it is matter of interpretation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the principle that applies is the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (LSP) and I would agree that you shouldn't have a method that only differs in it's output type in an inheriting class. Generally one would expect an implementing class to have the same semantics with respect to a method defined by an ancestor regardless of whether it's referred to from a variable typed as the base class or the implementing class.

The thing with principles, however, is that they're principles, not laws and it may, occasionally, be necessary to violate them.  Having said that, I don't recall using the `new` keyword for a long, long time if ever, to replace a parent class implementation.

I would regard the need for a `new` method as a code smell - a hint that there's probably something wrong with my design. Perhaps I'm trying to do too much in that class hierarchy or I've chosen the wrong pattern to apply.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in your statement here:

> A client would expect a class inheriting from MyBase to have a method named SampleMethod that returns an int array, but the child class doesn't.

This is untrue.  In fact the class *does* implement that method.  It just *also* implements its own version.

If an instance of `MyChild` is declared as so:

```
MyBase myBase = new MyChild();
```

This line:

```
int[] ints = myBase.SampleMethod();
```

Is valid and invokes the method you would expect.  In contrast, this line:

```
string[] strings = myBase.SampleMethod();
```

Would fail.  However, if you cast it to `MyChild`:

```
string[] strings = ((MyChild)myBase).SampleMethod();
```

This works exactly as you'd expect.

The point here is that inasmuch as the variable is known to be `MyBase`, it will behave exactly as you would expect regardless of your `new` implementation.  Thus polymorphism -- since it reacts to the *compile-time* type -- is unaffected, and has no implication to any OOP concepts.

Comment: I would disagree - the Liskov Substitution Principle, among other things, holds that derived classes should have covariance in the return types of methods - so for instance the inheriting class could return a `List<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` (though one would expect the signature to remain the same), but not vice versa. While I understand that you're actually providing a different implementation I think it's still a violation of the spirit of the principle in that a method with the same name and arguments behaves differently with respect to what type of variable/reference is being used.

Comment: I don't understand your example. Could you elaborate on the `List<T>` vs. `IEnumerable<T>` point as it relates to the OP's code?

Comment: I was simply pointing out that while `List<T>` is covariant with respect to `IEnumerable<T>`, `string[]` is certainly not with respect to `int[]`. Also, I'm not saying that it's not useful, just that I agree with the OP that it does fundamentally violate, at least one, OOP principle.

Comment: I just don't understand what ramification that could have in practice.  What "surprise" could actually happen in C# wherein because of this dissonance with OOP, the usage of `new` has created an artifact?

Comment: Let's say that you had `MyBase myBase = new MyChild();` because you wanted the base behavior in this instance. Now your code standard changes to require `var` declarations for all local variables.  You use a tool to update your code (say, Resharper) and it automatically changes it to `var mybase = new MyChild();` - oops. Best case, it doesn't compile any more. Worst case, the `new` method has the same signature and it now compiles, but it's broken.

Comment: IMO, your example is a failure of the refactoring tool.  If we are suggesting that the specification of C# is such that such tools are hard to write, I completely agree.  I just don't think it has anything to do with OOP.

Comment: I don't see how you can say that. LSP is the L in the 5 SOLID principles of object-oriented design, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design). Again, I'm not saying that it's necessarily wrong to use it, just know that you are, in fact, violating a fundamental principle. It should make you think twice and force you to have a pretty good reason.

Comment: +1. Though I agree with @tvanfosson's opinion on technical basis, I in fact like your answer as much.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the `new` keyword for cases, where an inherited interface has stronger restrictions on a method or property:

```
class Car
{
}

class Truck : Car
{
}

interface IDriver
{
    Car Vehicle { get; }
}

class Driver : IDriver
{
    public Car Vehicle { get; }

    public Driver(Car vehicle)
    {
        Vehicle = vehicle;
    }
}

interface ITrucker : IDriver
{
    new Truck Vehicle { get; }
}

class Trucker : Driver, ITrucker
{
    public new Truck Vehicle
    {
        get { return (Truck) base.Vehicle; }
    }

    public Trucker(Truck vehicle)
        : base(vehicle)
    {
    }
}
```

When I get some explicit `ITrucker` object, I get its `Truck` directly through the `Vehicle` property and do not need another cast, which is in some cases quite handy.

Anyway, this requires careful handling of such properties, if setting is allowed. Otherwise one can quickly get invalid casts. For readonly-Properties this is sometimes pretty convinient.

Answer (score -1):

It is basically used for hiding the base method. It is the correct way to mark a method in a derived class if you plan on hiding the method of the base class. If you don't use the new keyword, you get a compiler warning.

Using new in a derived class is pointless if you don't have a base method with the same signature.

Comment: In response to whoever down voted me, here is a quote from the MSDN article Knowing When to Use Override and New (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx). "The override modifier extends the base class method, and the new modifier hides it." And there is this: "When you build the project, you see that the addition of the Method2 method in BaseClass causes a warning. The warning says that the Method2 method in DerivedClass hides the Method2 method in BaseClass. You are advised to use the new keyword in the Method2 definition if you intend to cause that result." Same thing I said.